# Why integer arithmetic result showing different values in VB.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, integer

I have converted C# decrypt/encrypt functions to VB.NET. When I test the result in C# is showing below result but in VB.NET it throws an exception. Could you explain to me how C# showing the below result?

Below codes are tested in VS 2010 with 4.0 framework.

C# Code

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte bytTen = 10;
            int aa = 1527870874;
            int bb = 28904;
            int cc = 35756;
            Console.WriteLine((bytTen + aa) * bb + cc);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**Result: 726329420**

VB.NET Code

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim bytTen As Byte = 10
        Dim aa As Integer = 1527870874, bb As Integer = 28904, cc As Integer = 35756
        Console.WriteLine((bytTen + aa) * bb + cc)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Result: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

Comment: Those types are different between languages, yes. What would you like us to do: Explain the difference, help you test and learn this yourself, or refer you to some reading material?

Comment: I had converted c# decrypt / encrypt functions to VB.NET.  When I test the result in c# is showing above result but in VB.Net throwing exception.  Could you explain me how c# showing the above result ?

Comment: [-removeintchecks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/removeintchecks) compiler option.

Comment: Are you sure that this should be signed arithmetic and not unsigned?  I'm not sure that it changes anything, but wrap-around on overflow is more accepted for unsigned (e.g. for signed integers it's undefined behavior in C and C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# code is running as unchecked code (where integer overflow is ignored).

The VB code is running in as checked, where the runtime detects an integer overflow and throws an exception.

Comment: You might wanna add that it is configurable via the csproj file how it behaves.

Comment: How do I get same result in VB.NET ?

Comment: @Sureshv2 you know that the C# result is wrong, right? Since it overflows and you're ignoring it. You really want that on VB?

Comment: @Magnetron :  How do I get same result in VB.NET ?

Comment: @Magnetron: You can't make the connection between removing overflows and  the result being wrong.  The result still has consistency and is used in some types of calculations.  Just because you are unfamiliar with it doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Yeah, I should have made myself clearer, I was talking about mathematically wrong. For some uses it is a desired behaviour. As I don't know OP use case, I decided to point it out, as maybe they are not aware. That's why I asked if them really want that behaviour, instead of saying not to use.

Comment: @Magnetron It says in the question "encrypt/decrypt" which is the kind of application where I wouldn't be surprised to find by-design wrap-around behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To get the same result in VB, you need to check the project-level option "Remove integer overflow checks" on the "Advanced Compiler Settings" options via the "Compile" tab of the project options.

C# by default removes integer overflow checks (but this can also be changed on the C# project options), while VB by default has integer overflow checks.